# CSS adjacent sibling selectors - IE8 problem

Tags: css, siblings

I am creating a menu system using a UL/LI structure. I'm trying to use sibling selectors for hover/show-sub-menus.

I'm using this;

```
#MainMenu li.Sel ul li.HasSub a:hover+ul {
     display: block;
}
```

The UL structure would be something like this;

```
<ul id='MainMenu'>
    <li class='Sel'>
    <a href='#'>Click Me</a>
        <ul>
            <li class='HasSub'>
                <a href='#'>Hover Over Me</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Supposedly, when hovering over "Hover Over Me", the sibling ul should be displayed. It works great in Firefox, but not at all in IE8. I'm sure I've seen the '+' sibling selector used in IE8 before, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure IE is running in standards mode - put in a doctype like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358818(VS.85).aspx):

> The adjacent sibling combinator is a "plus sign" (+) character that separates two simple selectors. Whitespace is not significant.
>
> A selector of the form "E+F" matches element F when it immediately follows sibling element E in the document tree, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments). Element E and F must share the same parent and E must immediately precede F. To match the first child of the parent, use the :first-child pseudo-class.
>
> **Note**   Requires Windows Internet Explorer 7 or later.
> **Note**   **Combinators are enabled only in standards-compliant mode (strict !DOCTYPE).**

Comment: Hah. What's funny is, I dropped the doctype so that I could make an iframe 100% height of a table cell.

Thanks, guess I'm going to have to try and figure out the 100% height thing seperately. Any ideas? 

I'm going to have to use JS for IE6 menu effects.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

would it be simpler to add the hover on the li element and fix the hover for ie using this http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html

ie

```
#MainMenu li.Sel ul li.HasSub:hover {
     display: block;
}
```

Hope that helps

Josh