# Apply Padding to Elements with Certain Class after <h1>

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

What I would like to have done is for the last element (ex. paragraph `<p>` or unordered list `<ul>`) after the header1 `<h1>` element that has a class called `specialInstructionsNotes` to apply extra padding (30px) to only the **last** element with the class specialInstructionsNotes.

I've tried to incorporate the use of the `:first-of-type` and `:nth-of-type(1)` CSS3 selectors, but these selectors aren't transferred into IE8 (which is the lowest IE compatible browser I'm going to go). My goal is to be able to have the CSS settings (which is apply the padding to *only* the last element with the class `specialInstructionsNotes`) show in all the latest browsers and IE8+.

**Note:** There can be 3 or more elements that have this class applied to, just as long as the last element with the class `.specialInstructionNotes` has the padding at the very bottom. Sorry for any confusion.

Here is the full CSS I have so far:

```
.specialInstructionsNotes {
    color: #004abc;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding: 0 3%;
}    

h1 + p.specialInstructionsNotes + *, 
    h1 + ul.specialInstructionsNotes + *, 
    h1 + p.specialInstructionsNotes:nth-of-type(1), 
    h1 + ul.specialInstructionsNotes:nth-of-type(1) { 
        padding: 0 0 30px; 
    }

h1 + p.specialInstructionsNotes:first-of-type, 
h1 + ul.specialInstructionsNotes:first-of-type { 
    padding: 0; 
}
```

For the HTML, the elements are in one div and are the very top elements contained within the div. This is the HTML I currently have below for a few of the pages/scenarios I'm running into.

Page 1:

```
<div class="span12 main">
<h1><small>Proposal Narrative</small></h1>
            <p class="specialInstructionsNotes">A narrative proposal sufficient for peer review is required. Narratives can be up to <strong>5 single-spaced (12 pt. font) pages</strong>. Please note: the bibliography does <em>not</em> count towards the 5-page limit). The narrative should include:</p>
            <ul class="specialInstructionsNotes">
                <li>A statement of the objectives and significance of the proposed research/creative activity.</li>
                <li>A summary of relevant previous work by the applicant and/or others in the field.</li>
                <li>A description of the plan for accomplishing the objectives - include methodology, the roles of all personnel involved, and plans for access to any special resources.</li>
                <li>Although budget details and justification for personnel and non-personnel costs are required in the budget section, the narrative should make reference to all items, activities, and services of the requested funding.</li>
            </ul>
.
.
.
other elements added to the page
.
.
.
</div>
```

Page 2:

```
<div class="span12 main">
<h1><small>Brief Summary of Current Research/Creative Activities</small></h1>
            <p class="specialInstructionsNotes">A brief summary of the investigator’s research/creative activities, whether or not they are related to the activities proposed in this application.</p>
.
.
.
other elements added to the page
.
.
.
</div>
```

Page 3:

```
<div class="span12 main">
<h1><small>Supplemental Information</small></h1>
            <ul class="specialInstructionsNotes">
                <li>Supplemental information is not required. </li>
                <li>Please do not upload article reprints or book chapters. </li>
                <li>Uploaded files must be less than 1 megabyte in size. If you are attempting to upload scanned documents please use the OCR function to convert them to text before uploading. </li>
            </ul>
.
.
.
other elements added to the page
.
.
.
</div>
```

Page 4:

```
<div class="span12 main">
<h1><small>Publication List</small></h1>
            <ul class="specialInstructionsNotes">
                <li>A listing of publications and/or performances/creative activities for the last three years of the investigator(s)</li>
                <li>Vitae are not requested</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="specialInstructionsNotes">Each applicant on the proposal should upload a separate list. This list will be stored in the system and you may retrieve it in the future. If you or any other CoPI had previously uploaded a publication list, it will be shown below.<br /><br />
                <strong>Please upload your own publication list only.</strong>
            </p>
.
.
.
other elements added to the page
.
.
.
</div>
```

Please let me know if I need to explain further.

Comment: See if this is the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612587/css-adjacent-sibling-selectors-ie8-problem

Comment: It's sort of the issue I'm having. Only problem is the way I have it now works in Chrome and Firefox with Pages 1 and 4. I want to be able to apply padding to just the only element that has the class I want to apply padding to. It just so happens the padding issues I created don't work either in IE8. Only fear of converting as well is I'm using Bootstrap and am not sure if docking it down to that type will affect the structure.

Comment: @Abriel try to not use * selector

Comment: @raam86 Can you explain why so I have a better understanding of why I shouldn't? I'll definitely try not to.

Comment: I need some information. Are there other elements, perhaps randomly located, around these elements on some of the pages, or are all the elements classed with `specialInstructionNotes` and you are just attempting to target the final one (compatible with IE8)? Is your only goal to get `30px` of bottom space in that last element? If you want to update your question with more specifics rather than replying in a comment, that is great.

Comment: FYI, `:first-of-type` and `:nth-of-type(1)` are equivalent. If you're going to override one with the other, you may as well not include either of them at all.

Comment: Exactly. @Abriel, can you explain EXACTLY **what** you need to do and **how** ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios I've edited the question so as to clarify the question.

Comment: It's much clearer now, but I see that you have three different `padding` styles: `padding: 0 3%;`, `padding: 0 0 30px;` and `padding: 0;` - which elements should each of these styles be applied to?

Comment: Javascript or jQuery solutions ?

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ I accept those type of answers as well, but would much prefer to have a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Would the following workaround be acceptable: add `padding-bottom: 30px` to **all** `.specialInstructionsNotes` elements, but 'mask' it by setting `margin-top: -30px` to all `.specialInstructionsNotes` having preceding `.specialInstructionsNotes` sibling (i.e. `.specialInstructionsNotes { padding-top: 30px; } .specialInstructionsNotes + .specialInstructionsNotes { margin-top: -30px; }`)?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Can you insert that as an answer so I can properly read it? Thanks! :)

Comment: Is it possible that you might have three or more of these `.specialIsntructionNotes`? And are they always located before any other elements?

Comment: @ScottS Are you talking about elements that have `.specialInstructionNotes` under it? If so, then it's possible there may be 3 or more elements under the `<h1>` tag.

Comment: I'm asking if there may be 3 or more of these `<p>` and `<ul>` elements that have the `.specialInstructionNotes` class applied to it (all your examples show at most two), and I'm asking if these are always the first set of elements after the `<h1>` and all other elements follow (which your examples seem to indicate).

Comment: @ScottS Ok I'm sorry for the inclarification (which I'll add to the question). But yes there could be 3 or more elements that have the `.specialInstructionNotes` class applied to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about the workaround like this?

```
.specialInstructionsNotes {
   padding-bottom: 30px; /* set padding for all special elements */
}
.specialInstructionsNotes + .specialInstructionsNotes {
   margin-top: -30px; /* but make the next element hide the bottom padding
                         of its preceding siblings of the same class */
}
```

Comment: Of course this only works if all the `.specialInstructionNotes` are in fact the first "group" of the set (which it appears they are), and it works because we are dealing with things like `padding` (if it were a `color` change or something similar this would not work). But for this case, it seems like that is all the true, so it is a great workaround. I don't think there would be a general solution that supports IE8 if certain other properties were needing to be changed, and a javascript solution would likely be the only route to go.

Comment: If a particular `.specialInstructionNotes` is not the first "group", it still will be treated as the only one — with padding after it and without negative margin before it, which I suppose to be the expected behavior.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn This is super!! I can't believe how simple the solution really was and works fantastically! :) Thank you so much.

Comment: What's going on. Where's the bounty? we all know this is the only way possible

Answer (score 0):

If you need your solution to work for more than two occurences of `.specialInstructionsNotes` and you want the padding also on the first element if there is no other, then a js-solution would come in handy, even though it's not preferred by you ;)

**JS**

```
$('h1').each(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.specialInstructionsNotes:last').addClass('last-note');
});
```

Then it's easy to tackle the problem in CSS:

**CSS**

```
.specialInstructionsNotes.last-note {
    padding: 0 0 30px; 
}
```

**[See the exemplary Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhNpM/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add on of them to your `<head>` section:

With `CSS` (dirty but works!):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
    .main .specialInstructionsNotes{
        padding-bottom: expression(this.nextSibling==null?'30px':'3%');
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

You can also create an `ie.css` that contains the CSS above and call it like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

With `jQuery`:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".main :last-child.specialInstructionsNotes").css("padding-bottom", "30px dashed red");
        });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

References: http://mauzon.com/pseudoclasses-first-child-and-last-child-for-ie6/